# JavaScript video play null error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put a script into my HTML that allows for a video to play. The video does appear on the browser but the buttons associated with play/pause don't do anything. An error pops up on the play button and says that the line vid.play() is null. Here is my code.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("meme.mp4");

function playVideo(){

    vid.play();
}

function pauseVideo(){
    vid.pause();
}
```

Comment: what is the id of video tag in your html?

Comment: you sure your id = ``meme.mp4``?

Comment: `and says that the line vid.play() is null` - more likely the error is that vid is null, not that vid.play() is null

Comment: @JaromandaX it is null because getElementById couldn't find the video element.

Comment: @KiranShakya - I know why vid is null, I'm clarifying the statement that `vid.play()` is null according to the question - this is an incorrect statement

Comment: @JaromandaX ok didn't notice properly. Sorry

Comment: No harm no foul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thin you have made wrong in `document.getElementById("meme.mp4");` , you id may be wrong, it may be meme.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("meme");

function playVideo(){

    vid.play();
}

function pauseVideo(){
    vid.pause();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was one problem fixed. A second was to have the var=vid line under each function line. Not sure if that makes sense but it works now. Thanks.